# Creating Windows 8-like window in C# with Visual Studio 2012/Blend

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'd like to create desktop application which has Windows 8 style window(like [GitHub for windows](http://windows.github.com)). AFAIK Blend allows only to make Metro(Modern UI) apps' layouts(am I wrong?).

Comment: You could have a look at their own design blog article: https://github.com/blog/1151-designing-github-for-windows

Comment: You could use Expression Blend 4 to style your WPF application. If you have an MSDN subscription this should be available to you. An other way to get to work with Blend for Visual Studio is to download the preview with WPF, Silverlight and SketchFlow support. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702.

If you are not so good at the design side of things you should have a look at 3rd party control venders like Telerik. They often provide "Metro" themes to have you app look like windows store apps very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at [MahApps.Metro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro) or [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/).  They have a lot of Metro themed controls.

Comment: Thank you, I installed it, but [project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) doesn't work and I don't know how to use it. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Probably a temporary issue.  Here is a cached page of the documentation, http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:70E-R0rccmMJ:mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any .xaml file in my project directory. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Just create a new WPFWindow project and start modifying the XAML from there.